# Node Docker Runs, but can't see the application

Tags: node.js, docker, hapi.js

It appears that my Hapi app is running in a Docker container, but I can't hit it in the browser. I thought that `docker run -d -p 8080:3000` would have done it, but I guess not. I'm running boot to docker and neither `http://localhost:8080/hello` nor `http://192.168.99.100:8080/hello` is working.

I've tried tons of variations on this as well.

This is what I see when I run `docker inspect <container id>`:

```
Server running at: http://localhost:8080
```

Here's my Hapi.js server:

```
'use strict';

const Hapi = require('hapi');

// Create a server with a host and port
const server = Hapi.server({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3000
});

// Add the route
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path:'/hello',
    handler: function (request, h) {
        return 'hello world';
    }
});

async function start() {

    try {
        await server.start();
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        process.exit(1);
    }

    console.log(`App running at: ${server.info.uri}/hello`);
}

start();
```

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8.9.3

MAINTAINER My Name <email@email.com>

ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV PORT=3000
ENV user node

WORKDIR /var/www
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./

RUN cd /var/www && yarn

COPY . .

EXPOSE $PORT

ENTRYPOINT ["yarn", "start"]
```

Here's my package.json:

```
{
    "name": "my-app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "repository": "https://github.com/myname/myrepo.git",
    "author": "My Name",
    "license": "MIT",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "hapi": "17.2.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node ./src/server"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is not with Docker but how you configure the node server.

If you bind to `localhost` it will only be available from within the docker container. If you want to allow connections from the docker host either don't provide a hostname or use `0.0.0.0`.

```
const server = Hapi.server({
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 3000
});
```